# Validate Token Header Laravel JWTAuth

Tags: laravel, authentication, jwt, lumen

I'm making a simple API with Lumen, i use the JWTAuth library to make the tokens.

My login looks like:

```
try
                {
                    $this->validate($request, [
                        'email'    => 'required|email|max:255',
                        'password' => 'required'
                    ]);
                    try 
                    {
                        if (!$this->token = $this->jwt->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))):
                            throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json(['message' => 'Email/Contraseña invalidos'], JsonResponse::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY));
                        endif;
                    } 
                    catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) 
                    {
                        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json(['message' => 'Token expirado'], JsonResponse::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY));
                    }
                    catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) 
                    {
                        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json(['message' => 'Token invalido'], JsonResponse::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY));
                    }
                    catch (\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) 
                    {
                        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json(['message' => 'Sin token'], JsonResponse::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY));
                    }
                    return response()->json([
                        "token" => $this->token,
                        "email" => $this->jwt->user()->email,
                        "rfc" => $this->jwt->user()->rfc,
                        "nombre" => $this->jwt->user()->nombre,
                        "_uof" => $this->Cipher->EncryptCipher($this->jwt->user()->id),
                        "_rof" => $this->Cipher->EncryptCipher($this->jwt->user()->rfc)
                    ], 200);
                }
                catch(\Exception $error)
                {
                    throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json(['message' => 'Error al iniciar sesión el usuario'], JsonResponse::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY));
                }
```

That returns my token that is set on a React Frontend App, when i try to validate the token with curl or postman on my local enviroment with:

```
try
        {
            $this->payload = $this->jwt->getPayload($this->jwt->getToken())->toArray();
            var_dump($this->payload);
        }
        catch(\Exception $error)
        {
            var_dump($error->getMessage());
        }
```

My request looks like:

```
    curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8000/debtor/validateLogin/ \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9hcGltcGFsYS5yZWFsaG9zdC5jbG91ZFwvYXV0aFwvbG9naW4iLCJpYXQiOjE1MjcyODcyMTEsImV4cCI6MTUyNzI5MDgxMSwibmJmIjoxNTI3Mjg3MjExLCJqdGkiOiJyc3duZFh0NndzMXdhRGRvIiwic3ViIjoxLCJwcnYiOiI4N2UwYWYxZWY5ZmQxNTgxMmZkZWM5NzE1M2ExNGUwYjA0NzU0NmFhIiwibmFtZSI6IlVsaXNlcyBDYXJyZW9uIiwicmZjIjoiWEFYWDAxMDEwMTAwMCIsImF2YXRhciI6bnVsbH0.Ey1lMFYtSAE5f8pSrXjxnrMLGv2yOhl3DvwJo1qiTCI' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 29819986-830d-48f8-8724-25ce2fbf0af2' \
  -d '{}'
```

The token is on the Header of the request but when i make the request it throw this error "A token is required".

I've change the .htaccess to :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    #RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
# Fix authentication headers
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But still doesn't work, any advice?

Regards

Comment: Have you verified if your front end actually sends the token on each request?

Comment: The request is on Postman and like i show on the request the header Authorization Bearer is present.

Comment: what you show is it with curl or postman?

Comment: i edit my curl request

Comment: Have you verify if lumen or your jwtAuth library actually extract the token form the header i.e. from authorization?

Comment: The library actually doesn't read it :/
"A token is required"

Comment: any link to the library?

Comment: (https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/i)

Comment: did you see this https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication  ?

Comment: it doesnt red it :/

Comment: Have you created an issue on github?

Comment: A lot of people have the same issue but no response give :/

Comment: Personally I will suggest you implement you jwt auth manually without a library. That is what I do.

Comment: Do some findings on Google. For example https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-secure-a-rest-api-with-lumen--cms-27442